# Should std::array have move constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Moving can't be implemented efficiently (O(1)) on std::array, so why does it have move constructor ?

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have *any* constructors except the defaults generated by the compiler.

Comment: Where did you get this wrong piece of information (that `std::array` has a move constructor)?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes the compiler-generated move constructor.

Comment: Just because moving the whole array isn't O(1) doesn't mean it's not useful to gain O(1) in moving each element.

Comment: The unhelpful answer is "Of course std::array has an `O(1)` move constructor".  All instantiations of `std::array<int, 5>` take the same time to move/copy. `std::array<int, 6>`? That's a different type!

Answer (score 28):

`std::array` has a compiler generated move constructor, which allows all the elements of one instance to be moved into another. This is handy if the elements are efficiently moveable or if they are only movable:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  Foo()=default;
  Foo(Foo&&)
  {
    std::cout << "Foo(Foo&&)\n";
  }
  Foo& operator=(Foo&&)
  {
    std::cout << "operator=(Foo&&)\n";
    return *this;
  }
};

int main()
{
  std::array<Foo, 10> a;
  std::array<Foo, 10> b = std::move(a);
}
```

So I would say `std::array` should have a move copy constructor, specially since it comes for free. Not to have one would require for it to be actively disabled, and I cannot see any benefit in that.

Comment: Does it require that the element move constructor be `nothrow`? Or can it simply leave the operation in any legal state?

Comment: @MarkB good question, I hadn't considered it. This code works as is on gcc 4.7.3, even if I add a copy constructor. I will have to go read the standard, but my guess would be that a move from one container to the another cannot be expected to support the strong exception guarantee.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I believe you're right on the exception safety guarantee. That is, `std::array` move-constructor doesn't provide the strong exception safety guarantee. Only the basic one. See the first bullet of 12.8/15. My only doubt is if the "corrresponding subobject" is also an rvalue. What do you think?

Comment: @MarkB: "*Does it require that the element move constructor be nothrow?*" It's a compiler-generated move constructor, so it works with whatever it's given. If the underlying type is `noexcept` moveable, then the generated move constructor will be too. And if it isn't, then neither will the generated one be.

Comment: Isn't the answer supposed to be slightly more involved ? especially in the fact that an array, on the stack (possibly), cannot be pointer exchanged, therefore cannot be moved in O(1). The move constructor implicitely iterates over the elements of the aggregate and move each elements. This is not obvious, but the standard provides this powerful guarantee, the compiler expands quite a lot of hidden code here.

Answer (score 24):

To summarize and expand on other answers, `array<T>` should be moveable (when `T` itself is moveable) because:

- `T` may be efficiently moveable.
- `T` may be move-*only*.

Comment: lol, this says nothing. "should" "may" "may"... at least do you mean "should" by standard ?

Comment: @v.oddou This is stating why the fact that `array<T>` **is** movable (for movable T) makes sense.

Comment: @juanchopanza: this is just a letter to santa claus. this was already obvious prior to the question. yes we want what is stated. now we want to know **facts** about whether it is or not, and why.

Comment: Oh, actually, after re-reading your question I get it now. The question was "should" therefore the answer repeats the term, so its enough by itself. OK, approved. lol

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the standard:

23.3.2.2 array constructors, copy, and assignment [array.cons]

> The conditions for an aggregate (8.5.1) shall be met. Class array
>   relies on the implicitly-declared special member functions (12.1,
>   12.4, and 12.8) to conform to the container requirements table in 23.2. In addition to the requirements specified in the container requirements table, the implicit move constructor and move assignment
>   operator for array require that T be MoveConstructible or
>   MoveAssignable, respectively.

The move constructor and assignment operator are by far not free, they may not be provided.